# How to install particular set of files from deb package to /usr/lib?

Tags: deb

How to install particular set of files from deb package to /usr/lib ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the DEB package of your choice, e.g. `mc`

   ```
   apt-get download mc
   ```
2. Extract the package

   ```
   dpkg -x *.deb mc
   ```
3. All files of the package are now in `./mc` and you can copy what you need.

Comment: After downloading ms, is it possible to copy file from deb package to /usr/lib ?

Comment: Sure, after downloading and extracting. Now it's a simple file operation.

Comment: I am facing following error: cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/lib/libgmt.a’: Permission denied

Comment: Use `sudo ` to copy the files. Without sudo you have not the necessary rights.

Comment: I am unable to copy ".so" files.

Comment: Your question was answered. If you have problems to copy files, ask a new question. Accept this answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.

Comment: I typed sudo. Extract dir contains two types of files  (1)".a" (2)".so". I successfully copied ".a" files but i am unable to copy ".so" files.